# Find the general solution of ODE$ 1/16x"(t) + 4x(t) = rt(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution of this ODE, but my solution was told to be incorrect, here is the ODE

> $$1/16x"(t) + 4x(t) = r(t) \quad \text { where }r(t) = πt , -1<t<1$$

Here is what i have done:

$$ 1/16 x^2 +4 =0$$
 $$k = +- 8i$$
$$ X_h(t) = C_1 \cos8t + C_2 \sin8t$$

$$ \text{ for } X_p(t) = 1/D^2 + 64\times πt$$
 $$X_p(t) = πt/64$$

$$\text {General solution } = x(t) = X_c(t) + X_p(t)$$

$$ X(t) = C_1 \cos8t + C_2 \sin8t + πt/64$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\frac{1}{16}x''+4x=\pi t$$
This will fall to the method of undetermined coefficents. Since $r(t)$ is a first degree polynomial, we use $X_p (t) = A_1 t + A_0 $ as our guess. Plugging in,
$$4 A_1 t + 4 A_0 = \pi t$$
Thus, we have $A_1 = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $A_0 = 0$. Thus, $X_p(t)=\frac{\pi}{4}t$. The solution to the homogeneous equation is fairly trivial $$\frac{r^2}{16}+4 = 0 \\ r=\pm8i \\ X_h(t)=c_1\cos(8t)+c_2\sin(8t)$$ 
So, the final solution is $$X(t)=c_1\cos(8t)+c_2\sin(8t)+\frac{\pi}{4}t$$

Comment: is it possible to do this using Fourier series?

Comment: Not quite certain what you mean by this. Elaborate?

Comment: since r(t) is a sawtooth wave , its an odd function hence using Fourier coefficient a_0 and a_n will be 0 and if we calculate b_n ; b_n = 1/L integrate f(x) sin nπt/L dx